# React Infinite Loop axios.all

Tags: reactjs, server, axios

I'm hoping someone could help me out with this problem.

For some reason the axios.all is breaking my server, it's running on an infinite loop.

Here's my code below.

```
    export const getAllData = () => {
  return axios
    .all([axios.get(goalsAPI), axios.get(savingsAPI), axios.get(expensesAPI)])
    .then((res) => {
      let get = res.map((r) => r.data);
      console.log(get);
      return get;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

Later I'm calling it through useEffect with useState.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const [goals, setGoals] = useState(null);
  const [expense, setExpense] = useState(null);
  const [save, setSave] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllData().then((res) => {
      setGoals(res[0]);
      setSave(res[1]);
      setExpense(res[2]);
    });
  }, [save, expense, goals]);
```

I don't think it's coming from my useEffect, as I commented out the code and it seems that It's definitely from my axios call function.

Thanks in advance!

EDITED:
The moment I start my server this happens...
If anyone can understand what's going on this gif, please do answer.
[ERROR I'm facing...](https://gyazo.com/daab1d4cd523f8e43b21abf8f0110647)

This goes on forever then finally my vs code crashes.

Comment: what is the exact `error` you are facing? Under infinite loop you mean `stack overflow`? Also the `[save, expense, goals]` `dependency` array will call the function every time the `provided` values change.

Comment: Your `useEffect` hook is dependent on values that it sets, so I wouldn't be surprised if that's what's causing the infinite loop. Why do you have `save`, `expense`, and `goals` in the `useEffect` dependency array? They seem unnecessary and are likely causing the issue

Comment: I don't see how it would be coming from your axios call, but your `useEffect` will definitely be triggering an infinite loop the way it is setup. `[save, expense, goals]` should be `[setGoals, setSave, setExpense]`, your functions are dependencies, not the the values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` hook is dependent on values that it sets, so I wouldn't be surprised if that's what's causing the infinite loop. If you can remove `save`, `expense`, and `goals` from the dependency array, your problem would likely be solved:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getAllData().then((res) => {
    setGoals(res[0]);
    setSave(res[1]);
    setExpense(res[2]);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: the comments have already answered the question.

Comment: Hey! I actually used that in the first run although I thought it may solve the problem if I call the states instead. Turns out it's actually my server thats bugging out. Thanks for the reply!